# TypeError: can't convert undefined to object, using React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, javascript-objects, use-effect

I'm not able to set the data into react state variable. It's showing me that object is undefine.

I know it's illegal to pass an object as a child of a component. Is there any way I can get data from nested object. Here I'm using **Recursion**,but no luck.

```
// API Call
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "https://60d007f67de0b200171079e8.mockapi.io/bakery"
    );
    
    console.log('fetched data', response.data) // able to fetch the Data

    return response.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};


const extractData = (objects) => {
  const objectKeys = [];
  
  const values = Object.values(objects) // Object is undefine

  values.forEach(val => 
    val && typeof val === "object" ? extractNestedData(val) : objectKeys.push(val))
    
  return objectKeys;
  
}
const extractNestedData = (objects) => {
  const object = objects[0];
  const data = []
  data = extractData(object)
  return data;
}

export default function App() {
  const [bakery, setBakery] = useState([])
  const [flatBakery, setFlatBakery] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    
    let mount1 = true;
    if(mount1){
      
    fetchData().then((randomData) => {
      setBakery(randomData)
      console.log('bakery', bakery) // not able to set the data.

    })
  }
  
  return () => { mount1 = false;}
  
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    let mount2 = true;
    
    if (mount2) {
      
      setFlatBakery(extractNestedData(bakery));
    }
    
    return () => mount2 = false;
    
  }, [bakery])
  
  return (
    <div>
      Hello
    </div>
  );
}
```

Output
[image]

I'm struggling to fetch the data from Nested objects in React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because bakery is an empty list initially. You should only call extractNestedData after bakery data has been fetched.

Here's the updated code:

```
// API Call
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "https://60d007f67de0b200171079e8.mockapi.io/bakery"
    );

    console.log("fetched data", response.data); // able to fetch the Data

    return response.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

const extractNestedData = (objects) => {
  const objectKeys = [];

  const values = Object.values(objects);

  values.forEach((val) =>
    val && typeof val === "object"
      ? extractNestedData(val)
      : objectKeys.push(val)
  );

  return objectKeys;
};

export default function App() {
  const [bakery, setBakery] = useState([]);
  const [flatBakery, setFlatBakery] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let mount1 = true;
    if (mount1) {
      fetchData().then((randomData) => {
        setBakery(randomData);
        console.log("bakery", bakery); // not able to set the data.
      });
    }

    return () => {
      mount1 = false;
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let mount2 = true;

    if (mount2 && bakery.length > 0) {
      setFlatBakery(extractNestedData(bakery[0]));
    }

    return () => (mount2 = false);
  }, [bakery]);

  return <div>Hello</div>;
}
```

Comment: Ohh I get it.Thanks a lot. Because of this condition i have successfully wasted my whole day.

Comment: I am glad I could help. If it works, please accept the answer so that others can benefit as well :)